# What can I do to install sort package (Haskell) that keeps failing?

Tags: haskell, package, cabal

I am trying to install the sort package (Haskell), but it keeps failing even though I have the latest version of cabal.

So I updated my cabal : `cabal update`
But when I run `cabal install sort`, it failed. Then I tried to run it with `--minimize-conflict-set`, but it did not work as well. What can I do?

```
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: base-4.12.0.0/installed-4.1... (user goal)
[__1] next goal: binary (user goal)
[__1] rejecting: binary-0.8.7.0 (constraint from user target requires
==0.8.6.0)
[__1] trying: binary-0.8.6.0/installed-0.8...
[__2] next goal: containers (user goal)
[__2] rejecting: containers-0.6.2.1 (conflict: binary =>
containers==0.6.0.1/installed-0.6...)
[__2] rejecting: containers-0.6.1.1, containers-0.6.0.1/installed-0.6...,
containers-0.6.0.1, containers-0.5.11.0, containers-0.5.10.2,
containers-0.5.10.1, containers-0.5.9.2, containers-0.5.8.2,
containers-0.5.7.1, containers-0.5.7.0, containers-0.5.6.3,
containers-0.5.6.2, containers-0.5.6.1, containers-0.5.6.0,
containers-0.5.5.1, containers-0.5.5.0, containers-0.5.4.0,
containers-0.5.3.1, containers-0.5.3.0, containers-0.5.2.1,
containers-0.5.2.0, containers-0.5.1.0, containers-0.5.0.0,
containers-0.4.2.1, containers-0.4.2.0, containers-0.4.1.0,
containers-0.4.0.0, containers-0.3.0.0, containers-0.2.0.1,
containers-0.2.0.0, containers-0.1.0.1, containers-0.1.0.0,
containers-0.5.9.1, containers-0.5.8.1 (constraint from user target requires
==0.6.2.1)
[__2] fail (backjumping, conflict set: binary, containers)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: binary, containers, base, ghc
Try running with --minimize-conflict-set to improve the error message.
```

```
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: base-4.12.0.0/installed-4.1... (user goal)
[__1] trying: containers-0.6.2.1 (user goal)
[__2] next goal: ghc (user goal)
[__2] rejecting: ghc-8.6.5/installed-8.6... (conflict: containers==0.6.2.1,
ghc => containers==0.6.0.1/installed-0.6...)
[__2] rejecting: ghc-8.6.5 (conflict: base==4.12.0.0/installed-4.1..., ghc =>
base<0 && ==4.12.*)
[__2] rejecting: ghc-8.6.4, ghc-8.6.1, ghc-8.4.4, ghc-8.4.3, ghc-8.4.1,
ghc-8.2.2, ghc-8.2.1 (constraint from user target requires ==8.6.5)
[__2] fail (backjumping, conflict set: base, containers, ghc)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: containers, base, ghc
```

Comment: Does `v2-install` not work?  The `install` aka `v1-install` is conceptually broken in that it requires you to install one version globally, locking you in and causing version conflicts between projects.

Comment: No it did not work 'cabal install sort v2-install', it failed again.

Comment: What is the exact command you are trying? I'm really struggling to connect the output shown here with what I would expect from `cabal install sort`. For one thing, there's a bunch of user goals that are not `sort`; where did those come from? For another, there's no user goal that is `sort`; why not? What's more, I've just looked at `sort` on Hackage, and it has pretty much 0 dependencies. So all this dependency solving must be coming from somewhere else. What are you actually doing? Do you have a sandbox? Do you have a cabal file or project in the same directory? We need way more info.

Comment: @KaleJoe I wasn't suggesting you add `v2-install` as a package to install.  The suggestion in it's entirety is `cabal v2-install --lib sort`.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson though I'd agree that the new-style Cabal commands are overall much better, I've always found the criticism of the v1-commands exaggerated. Sure, it would often cause conflicts – but it's not like those couldn't be resolved, only, it could require large-scale reinstalls. (But that's what new-install has to do as well, only it does it under the hood.) I _don't_ think this problem has anything to do with v1-install, it rather looks like something is fundametally incompatible with the GHC version.

Comment: I face a similar problem when I try to install a package outside a project, only it objects agains `process`, rather than `containers`. Possibly me and Kale are witnessing two instances of the same bug.

Comment: To help we'd need much more information.  You'll probably be better off starting fresh by removing `.ghc` and `.cabal`, trying again, and if you get stuck then include the version of GHC, Cabal, installation source, exact commands..  Even better if you can use a container or something transferable to others to reproduce your issue, such as `docker run --rm -it -u tommd tommd/haskell` and `cabal update ; cabal install sort` or similar.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Indeed this seems to be an error in the `.ghc/.../environments/default`. It has an entry `package-id process-1.6.5.1-9872203aea42fb5652d0920fddefeb54b4ca067e3b287e3fad61e26e7e16d857`. In a newly created `.ghc/.../default` the entry for `process` is different: `package-id process-1.6.5.0`. Possibly this is the problem. But I am not sure what to make of it.